# Uploaded files not found in google drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I am just starting with google drive, I have successfully uploaded files and list all my files but I can't seem to find my uploaded files in my google drive?

```
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading credentials', err);
    const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
    const { client_email, private_key } = credentials;

    auth = new google.auth.JWT(
      client_email,
      null,
      private_key,
      SCOPES,
    );
    drive = google.drive({
      version: 'v3',
      auth,
    });
  });
```

`List of files from drive`

```
drive.files.list({}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const files = res.data.files;
    console.log(files);
    if (files.length) {
    files.map((file) => {
      console.log(file);
    });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found');
    }
  });
```

`Upload file`

```
const fileMetadata = {
    name: 'test_only', // file name that will be saved in google drive
  };

  const media = {
    mimeType: 'image/png',
    body: fs.createReadStream('image.png'), // Reading the file from our server
  };

    // Uploading Single image to drive
  drive.files.create(
    {
      resource: fileMetadata,
      media: media,
    },
    async (err, file) => {
      console.log(err);
      if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log(file.data.id);
      }
    }
  );
```

[image: Results on list of files]

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current situation is as follows.

- From your authorization script, it is found that you are using the service account.

  ```
    auth = new google.auth.JWT(
      client_email,
      null,
      private_key,
      SCOPES,
    );
  ```
- You can upload the files and retrieve the file list using your script.

#### Modification points:

- From `I can't seem to find my uploaded files in my google drive`, I thought that the reason of your issue is to upload the files using the service account. In this case, the Drive of the service account is different from your Google Drive. By this, the uploaded files cannot be shown in your Google Drive. And also, the Drive of service account cannot be directly shown with the browser.

As a workaround for showing the uploaded files in your browser, I would like to the following workarounds.

#### Workaround 1:

In this workaround, a folder in your Google Drive is shared with the email of the service account. And the uploaded files are put to the shared folder. By this, you can see the uploaded files using the service account in your Google Drive.

#### Workaround 2:

In this workaround, a folder in the service account is shared with the email of your Google account. And the uploaded files are put to the shared folder. By this, you can see the uploaded files using the service account in the browser.